# Error while installing uml lab in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, uml

i was trying to install uml lab in eclipse juno,but no matter how much i try i am always getting this error message:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
```

uml lab is just not getting installed .please help me out i need to complete my work.

Answer (score 1):

what error do you get? You find this information in the details or in the Error Log view. Just a guess: Is the update site of Eclipse Juno activated? Have a look at "Window -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites". There should be an active entry pointing to "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno".

Alternatively you could install the UML Lab Standalone RCP (http://www.uml-lab.com/download/).

Best regards
Manuel